# expanding a html table

Tags: html, button, datatable

First post, ambitious n00b here, please be kind. It is about a huge data table containing about 28500 entries. It is paginated in parts of 15 entries with "newer"/"older" navigation buttons starting from most recent entries. There is no way to navigate back, than pressing "older" button and as you understand, it would need thousand clicks to reach oldest part .
I copy button configuration from source code here

```
<button class="btn btn-sm active float-left ii__votes_btn invisible" type="button" data-uid="75091" data-vpp="15" data-page="-1" data-total="28186">
```

Νεότερες


Παλαιότερες

Is it possible to change data-vpp from 15 to some o
ther, bigger number, so I get more entries to copy? If not, are any other ways to get way more entries than 15?

Comment: Usually, a datatable is generated server-side -- at least its data it. Anyway a little more context would not be amiss in order to help others to answer your question.

Comment: Like what? The whole table maybe? Anyway, source code is open , and it's possible .